# Wrong output of MergeSort program in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, mergesort

I'm trying to write a basic merge sort code which is giving the wrong output. My input array is `{4,2,6,1,9,5,6,78,9,34,74,86,14,3,0}` The output I'm getting is `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 9 14 74 32696 802952496 1 1` which is definitely wrong, But I can't find the wrong part of the code.

`Sort` Function take the array divides it in 2 and merge sorts it in initial array.
`MergeSort` Recursively divides the array till only one element is left

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void Sort(int *arr,int low,int mid,int high)                          //Sorting algo
{
    int n1=mid-low+1,n2=high-mid;
    int arr1[n1];
    int arr2[n2];
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)arr1[i]=arr[i+low];
    for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)arr2[j]=arr[mid+j+1];
    
    int i=0,j=0,it=low;
    while(i<n1 && j<n2)
    {
        if(arr1[i]<=arr2[j])
        {
            arr[it]=arr1[i];i++,it++;
        }
        else 
        {
            arr[it]=arr2[j];j++,it++;
        }
    }
    while(i<n1){
        arr[it]=arr1[i];i++;it++;
    }
    while(j<n2){
        arr[it]=arr2[i];j++;it++;
    }
}

void MergeSort(int* arr,int low,int high)      //Recursive Merge Function
{
    int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
    if(low<high)
    {
        MergeSort(arr,low,mid);
        MergeSort(arr,mid+1,high);
        Sort(arr,low,mid,high);
    }
    
    
}
int main() {
    int arr[]={4,2,6,1,9,5,6,78,011,34,74,86,14,3,0};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])-1;
    MergeSort(arr,0,n);
    
    for(int a:arr)
    {
        cout<<a<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an FYI, `int arr1[n1];` is not standard C++ unless `n1` is a constant expression. Doing this is using a compiler extension to the language.

Comment: The other thing to point out is that you should be testing your code on just 4 or 5 values, not 15 values.  If your code doesn't work with 4 values, it isn't going to work for 15 values.  Working with a much smaller set of data will allow you to follow the code better to see where the problem is.  Also, `011` is not the number 11, it is an octal value equal to 9.  A leading 0 in an integer literal means that the number is octal, not decimal.  Last, `int arr1[n1];` Change that line and the next one to --> `std::vector<int> arr1(n1), arr2(n2);`

Comment: @crashmstr Ty for the info sir, will making the array at run time work? or what do I need to do to make it standard C++?

Comment: @Daniel -- Read my comment as to how to make it standard C++.  Use `std::vector` (and make sure you `#include <vector>`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sir, I've been taught that vectors are arrays at backend so isn't it basically the same?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, a vector is a dynamic array wrapped in a convenient class.  But this really isn't about what is in the backend, it is about C++ syntax.  Plain arrays in C++ cannot be "dynamic" -- the size must be determined by a constant expression.  A `std::vector` is different in that you can specify the number of elements dynamically.  As an experiment, if you have Visual Studio instead of g++, take your code and try to compile it in Visual C++.  You will see that the code will not compile because of those arrays you have.  What would you do to solve that problem if you only have Visual C++?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ty Sir! Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
while(j<n2){
    arr[it]=arr2[i];j++;it++;
}
```

Should be:

```
while(j<n2){
    arr[it]=arr2[j];j++;it++;
}
```

What was wrong? You were accessing the index `i` instead of `j`.

Note: This kind of code:

```
int n1=mid-low+1,n2=high-mid;
int arr1[n1];
int arr2[n2];
for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)arr1[i]=arr[i+low];
for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)arr2[j]=arr[mid+j+1];
```

Is ugly, too ugly. Please use spaces, they are free!